# SageMaker Model Registry Sharing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

Is it possible to share a model registry completely between Dev and Prod environment? So my idea is to create 10000 models in dev and maybe select 2000 from there to work in prod. I am planning to use AWS model registry. So if I do the training and testing and hyperparameter tuning in my AWS dev environment, is it possible to then share the registry in prod? The obvious reason is that it does not make sense to use the prod to do the training and testing again.

Please advise!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how you define Dev and Prod.

- If by Dev and Prod you mean different AWS account (which is a good practice - see [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/organizing-your-aws-environment/benefits-of-using-multiple-aws-accounts.html) and [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/aws-building-a-secure-cross-account-continuous-delivery-pipeline/)), you cannot share fractions of a model registry from a given account to another account, but you can create triggers to export models from one model registry to another, as documented in this blog post https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/patterns-for-multi-account-hub-and-spoke-amazon-sagemaker-model-registry/
- If your Dev and Prod live in the same AWS account and you are just looking for ways to differentiate them, you can use:

  - Model Registry Status information
  - Tags

Comment: Thank you. Our dev and prod are different AWS account - according to best practices, that is what we do. 

Now, I know there is an approval process for approving a model. But after a bunch of model is approved, then how does it copied/moved to production? You mentioned "export" model - what does it mean? 
BTW: thanks for the link  - please allow me to ask for any clarification if I am stuck understanding it.

Comment: of course! by "export" I mean custom copy mechanism, using AWS services. You can create a Lambda function in account A to register the model in the model registry of account B. Or you can also do a pull-based approach, where updates to the model registry in account A trigger EventBridge events, that trigger a Lambda in account B to copy the model details from Model Registry A to model registry B

Comment: That is great and promising. Our admin is concerned about security. But if it is possible to copy the registry by lambda or EventBridge - that would be great. Are you saying the copy mechanism will copy the model(s) itself or the registry information including model lineage or copy both? If model registry or lineage cannot be copied, I am sure the model itself (the tar.gz file) can be copied over. 

Is there anywhere - any code example you can please refer to so that I can see how it is done? I am new to AWS and any help will be super useful.

In all these do you see any security concern?

Comment: I could not find any document or code where they are doing model registry copy. If you know the command or the code example, I would be really thankful to you.

Comment: there is no "copy" command to go from one model registry to another. You would need to use the create_model_package API to log all necessary information in the model registry of account B https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.create_model_package, and optionally copy the docker image and S3 model artifact if you want them in the prod account too. The blog above contains full example code snippets

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I see that the "PULL" mechanism might work for us. So the gist of this "PULL" mechanism is that model registry and model lineage can be 'exported" (same/similar to "copying" I believe) from QA to Prod. Our plan is to build and train the models in QA and deploy and use them in Prod.

So my question is : is the above understanding right ??

Comment: Secondly: I see this in the site:
Exporting this information to different accounts is possible as of this writing using dedicated model metadata. Model metadata can be exchanged through different mechanisms (for example by emitting and forwarding a custom EventBridge event, or by writing to an Amazon DynamoDB table). A detailed description of these processes is beyond the scope of this post.

So does it mean we have to create a DynamoDB instance or we can use EventBridge to accomplish this.

Again, THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Answer (score 0):

I think AWS just released the cross account model registration feature not long ago, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-registry-version.html#model-registry-version-xaccount